# How do you view profile information with MiniProfiler from unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, mvc-mini-profiler

I am trying to profile various portions of a .Net Core 2.2 library. I decided to use unit testing since I have unit tests for many of the areas I want to profile. I am trying to use StackExchange's MiniProfiler but I don't see anything in the documentation about how to view the profiling results.

I created a property on my test fixture:
    public MiniProfiler Profiler
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

and populated it in the constructor of the fixture:

```
this.Profiler = MiniProfiler.StartNew("CRMODataDataSource Profiler");
```

Then call my code I want to profile:

```
        using (Fixture.Profiler.Step("TestDefaultWithDynamic"))
        {
            testValue =
                (testEntity.HasPrimaryKey() == true)
                && testEntity.GetPrimaryKey().KeyValues.All(v =>
                {
                    if (null != v.Value)
                    {
                        return !CrmEntityFixture.ValueIsDefault((dynamic)v.Value);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                );
        }
        Assert.True(testValue);
```

I installed the nuget packages using:
    Install-Package MiniProfiler.AspNetCore -IncludePrerelease

The [documentation](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/) shows a UI and talks about it but never mentions how to start the UI. I have searched the output folders and didn't find any files that resemble profile data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit tests doesn't have any web ui, instead it behaves almost the same as a console.
Checkout this page: https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/ConsoleDotNetCore

```cs
// Default configuration usually works for most, but override, you can call:
// MiniProfiler.Configure(new MiniProfilerOptions { ... });

var profiler = MiniProfiler.StartNew("My Profiler Name");
using (profiler.Step("Main Work"))
{
    // Do some work...
}

Console.WriteLine(profiler.RenderPlainText());
// or for the active profiler:
Console.WriteLine(MiniProfiler.Current.RenderPlainText());
```